# django-filter: Input formats with DateFromToRangeFilter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io) in my project. Is it possible to use `input_formats` or `format` with `DateFromToRangeFilter` widget.

Field definition:

```
service_date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()
```

Change widget:

```
self.form.fields['service_date'].widget = forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(input_formats=["%d-%m-%Y"])
```

The error:
[image]

How can I use `input_formats` with `DateFromToRangeFilter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out `DateFromToRangeFilter` contains two `DateFields`. We can simply access them and update the `input_formats`.

```
# First field - from
self.form.fields['service_date'].fields[0].input_formats = ['%d-%m-%Y']
# Last field - to
self.form.fields['service_date'].fields[-1].input_formats = ['%d-%m-%Y']
```